# How do you convert a Box<dyn Trait> to a Rc<dyn Trait>?

Tags: memory-management, rust, trait-objects

I have a function which receives a `Box<dyn Trait>` and needs to convert that into an `Rc<dyn Trait>` to share read-only ownership within the thread.

With a `Box<T>` of some `T: Sized`, we can do `Rc::new(*my_box)`, but unfortunately [that doesn't work for unsized trait objects](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42478).

Here's an oversimplified example which hopefully clarifies the problem:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

pub trait Trait {}

pub struct Foo {}
impl Trait for Foo {}

fn main() {
    let trait_box: Box<dyn Trait> = Box::new(Foo {});
    let trait_rc: Rc<dyn Trait> = Rc::new(*trait_box); // -> Error
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e2997ab946438c75129e5c71ae49f0e7)

I saw [some things here and there](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1283) about exposing the internal `RcBox` to support moving between `Box` and `Rc`, but AFAIK it's not usable today.

Is there a workaround for this?

Or if this type of conversion isn't possible, what is the recommended method for storing a trait object which can be mutated up to a point, and then after that point be shared immutably with the rest of the program?

Using a `Rc<RefCell<dyn Trait>>` seems like overkill when I know I just have a single owner up to that point...

Comment: Not an answer, but you could use `Rc<Box<dyn Trait>>` and keep it on the heap

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Rc<T>` [implements `impl<T> From<Box<T, Global>>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#impl-From%3CBox%3CT%2C%20Global%3E%3E) so you can just use [`into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html#tymethod.into):

```rust
let trait_rc: Rc<dyn Trait> = trait_box.into();
```

[Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7189a6b0a6a82d71d61ba8dc74672169)